# How to add value from Dictionary having value as dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am having dictionary whose value is another dictionary

for ex. `["1": ["1623699578": 1.08], "2": ["1216047930": 6.81]]`

inner dictionary will have only one value

i want to do sum of 1.08 and 6.81

for now i am tried to just iterate dictionary and taking value using `dict.values.first` and adding. But i not sure if its best way

is there any best way to do this?

Comment: What if each inner-dictionary has multiple values? Sum all those too?

Comment: I'm sure you have tried something, what have you tried? What part of it doesnt work? ] Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The "best" way is opinion based and out of scope for SO.

Comment: inner dictionary has only one value

Comment: If there is only one value for the inner dictionary you could do `dict.compactMap { $0.value.values.first }.reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sum all the dictionary value's values. We use `reduce` to combine the dictionary collections into a single value.

Code:

```
let dict = ["1": ["1623699578": 1.08], "2": ["1216047930": 6.81]]

let sum: Double = dict.reduce(into: 0) { partialResult, pair in
    partialResult += pair.value.values.reduce(0, +)
}

print(sum)
```

This will also sum the inner-dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

Another notation for what @George proposed can be:

```
let sum = dict.values.compactMap { $0.values.first }.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1 }
```